# GNOME top bar tray icon shows error icon "A problem occured when checking for updates"

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, top-bar

I installed a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and a couple of applications. Now on this relatively fresh system I have this error icon in the top bar in the tray icon section.

[image: see image]

When clicking it, it shows only a text  "A problem occurred when checking for updates" and the options "Show updates", "Show notifications", "Preferences". None of the options does anything when clicking one of them.

How can I find out what this error belongs to? How can I fix it?

Comment: I just guess this is the `apt` update (Ubuntu packages), you can try to run it from the command line, at least you will see better error messages:
`apt update` then `apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not it. i could run `apt upate` with no errors. My solution was now to simply reinstall Ubunutu 20.04 freshly.

Comment: Any good reason to install 20.04 in 2022? Why not 22.04 (both are LTS).

Comment: @redseven because i ran in a couple of situations where packages for 22.04 were not provided yet. I prefer my environment as stable as possible. Btw the error did not occur anymore, not sure what it was!

Comment: Does `apt dist-upgrade` also finish with no error? And after all package updated (and you rebooted) do you still have that notification icon?

Comment: Yes, i updated all packages and the error persisted still after rebooting. That is why i reinstalled the system with Ubuntu 20.04 as a workaround. Until now, this error did not appear anymore. I am just curious how i can find out in the future how to debug this. Is there a way to list all running tray icon applications? This would probably identify the culprit.
About the reason why i am using Ubuntu 20.04 and not 22.04: MongoDB is not yet released for 22.04, which i am using on a daily basis. See: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-over-ubuntu-22-04/159931